# How to solve npm ERR! missing script: dev

Tags: npm, vue.js

I have installed node.js.
Next, I installed cnmp with command

```
npm install -g cnpm --registry=https://registry.npm.taobao.org
cnpm install
```

when I tried command `cnpm run dev`
there is a error:

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Harry\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Harry\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-03T02_48_22_663Z-debug.log
```

so I moved the package.json from `C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cnpm` to `'C:\Users\Harry\package.json'`
but I still got an error:

```
npm ERR! missing script: dev

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-03T02_51_46_194Z-debug.log
```

and I also tried methods of similar problems, such as edit the script in package.json, it still doesn't work.

Comment: After moving `package.json`, you will need to run `cnpm install` again

Comment: I tried but it still does not work......

Comment: Did you check if your your `package.json` actually contains a `scripts` section with a `dev` command?

Comment: "scripts": {
    "test": "npm run lint -- --fix && npm run test-local",
    "test-local": "egg-bin test",
    "lint": "eslint bin lib test/*.js",
    "ci": "npm run lint && npm run test",
    "autod": "autod"
  },       it doesn't contain dev in scripts

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps you are using the Vue CLI 3?  If yes, there is no "dev" build script.  Earlier versions of the Vue 2 boilerplate project had a "dev" script - but no longer.

Instead use the "serve" script and your Vue project will run as dev

```
npm run serve
```

See the scripts that are configured with Vue CLI 3 in the **package.json** file

```
"scripts": {
         "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
         "build": "vue-cli-service build",
         "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"    },
```

Hope that solves your issue.